# Split HTML table cell data

Tags: python, html, postgresql

I have an HTML table that contains a column named Attached Files. This column contains the name(s) of the attached documents. I want to be able to open these documents when they are clicked. But I cannot do this because the HTML table shows multiple file names in a single table cell. Here is how I get the file names from the PostgreSQL database.

```
{{for (i,e) in enumerate(rows):}}
<tr>
<td>{{=T("%(value_5)s") % dict(value_5=e.attached_files)}}</td>
</tr>
```

attached_files is the column name in my database. What I think I want to do is, separate/split the file names then apply HTML link using the href attribute.

**My project is in Python (I don't want any JavaScript solutions).**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.attached_files` is a list which you are rendering (representing) as a list. Add one more loop to iterate over this list and represent each file as a table data within a table row

```
{{for (i,e) in enumerate(rows):}}
<tr>
{{for fname in e.attached_files:}}
<td>{{=T("%(value_5)s") % dict(value_5=fname)}}</td>
{{ pass }}
</tr>
```

if you do not want it on separate columns, place the fields on seperate spans within a table data

```
{{for (i,e) in enumerate(rows):}}
<tr><td>
{{for fname in e.attached_files:}}
<span>{{=T("%(value_5)s") % dict(value_5=fname)}}</span>
{{ pass }}
</td></tr>
```

Comment: I'm getting some error. Code for the HTML block (including your suggestion).
`{{for (i,e) in enumerate(rows):}}
 <tr>
 <td>{{=T("%(value_1)s") % dict(value_1=e.title)}}</td>
 <td>{{=T("%(value_2)s") % dict(value_2=e.description)}}</td>
 <td width= "140px">{{for usr in e.receiver:}}
   <li>{{=usr.first_name}} {{=usr.last_name}}</li>
      {{pass}}
 </td>
  
  <td width= "200px">{{=T("%(value_4)s") %                   dict(value_4=e.send_time)}}</td>
                {{for fname in e.attached_files:}}
  <td>{{=T("%(value_5)s") % dict(value_5=fname)}}</td>
  {{ endfor }}
  </tr>
  {{pass}}`

Comment: @MJB: What template engine are you using. I found it to be different than django / jinja and thought may be there should be endfor but seems you found out what is appropriate. In any case, if you do not want it as a separate column, put it in a span within a table data

Comment: I don't know which template engine I'm using (I guess its just pure Python). Anyways, I fixed the separate column issue by looping inside the table cell.
`<td>{{for fname in e.attached_files:}} 
 {{=T("%(value_5)s") % dict(value_5=fname)}} 
{{ pass }}
</td>`